# Extjs 4 / Sencha Architect - two same region in border layout

Tags: extjs4, sencha-architect, border-layout

I am using Extjs 4 in Sencha Architect. I have 2 buttons when I press on first one I get 'Panel_1" displays at the bottom. I made it using border layout on parent panel and south region on child panel "Panel_1".

[image: border layout]

now I need to do the same thing and display "Panel_2" at the same place when button_2 pressed. but seems like I cannot set two panels at same region (south) in border layout.

Any another idea about how to accomplish that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a container in the south region with a card layout. Add both of your panels to this container and then use the `southContainer.setActiveItem(card)` function in your button handler to show the correct panel when you press the relevant button.